# What class is returned when requesting distinct NSManagedObject property instances from Core-Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a simple situation, I have a CDPerson class which is an subclass of NSManagedObject. This class contains a 1 to 1 relationship to a CDHair class (also a subclass of NSManagedObject). The relationship property on the CDPerson class is named "hair".

I want to get at the distinct CDHair instances actually in use by all the CDPerson instances in the ManagedObjectContext.

I am fetching a distinct list of properties (and this part works),

```
 NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Person"];
 fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = YES;
 fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[@"hair"];
 fetchRequest.resultType =NSDictionaryResultType;
 fetchRequest.predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"hat=='no'"];
 fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = YES;
 NSArray* fetchResults = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

fetchResults in an NSArray as expected. fetchResults[0] is a NSDictionary as expected. fetchResults[0][@"hair"] resolves to something, but I can't tell what it is. It's po description is

```
0x8b7b120 <x-coredata://C7E53293-94C7-444D-8162-167B1D66A961/Hair/p33>
```

It seems to have no selectors. If I cast it to a CDHair and try to use a property on the instance, .color for example, I receive a "unrecognized selector" error.

```
CDTest[2865:70b] -[_NSObjectID_48_0 color]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8ba8670
```

First, I have no idea what the class _NSObjectID_48_0 is. 
Second, I figured that the property retrieved from the fetch would be a CoreData instance of CDHair, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Nor is it a NSManagedObject.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Could you post all the code for your fetchRequest

Comment: Are you sure that the entity name that you have specified in the fetchRequest is "CDHair" ? "/Hair/p33" signifies that it is an object whose entity Name is "Hair" having ID as "p33"

Comment: For the record, as you explicitly ask for `NSDictionaryResultType`, you're not going to get any `NSManagedObject`s. Which means you're not going to get implicit faulting or any of the other object graph niceties. On the other hand, dictionaries are thread-safe and you're guaranteed not to accidentally trigger any trips to the backing store — which may have to wait for a lock to be released if you've got multithreaded store access going on.

Comment: Thank you all. I see what I was really missing was [context objectWithID:] to get the actual object back.

Comment: @RyanG posted all fetchRequest code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have explicitly set

```
fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
```

the fetch request returns a dictionary, and relationships to other object are represented
by a `NSManagedObjectID`. You can retrieve the corresponding object from the "managed
object id" with the `objectWithID` or `existingObjectWithID` method. For example:

```
NSManagedObjectID *mid = fetchResults[0][@"hair"];
CDHair *hair = (CDHair *)[context objectWithID:mid];
NSString *color = hair.color;
```

But it may be easier to set `propertiesToFetch` to the actual properties of `CDHair`
that you are interested in, for example

```
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[@"hair.color"];
```

Then the result array would look like

```
(
{
    "hair.color" = green;
},
{
    "hair.color" = red;
}
)
```

and you can access it like

```
NSString *color = fetchResults[0][@"hair.color"];
```

Comment: Ah! [context objectWithID:mid]! CoreData has a lot of gotchas. Thanks!

Comment: @SamuelRenkert: That's why I mentioned existingObjectWithID as well, and also the alternative approach that avoids the object ids. You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You asked for a relationship property of the `CDPerson` entity. This will only result in the returned dictionaries being populated with the `objectID` of the related `CDHair` of these persons.

The resulting dictionaries are populated with `NSObjectID` objects relating to the `CDHair` elements of the result set (all existing persons). This is why you could not use these objects directly to get to their properties. you can get the actual objects by using the `existingObjectWithID:error:`, `objectWithID:` of the `NSManagedObjectContext` and passing it the returned IDs.

If you like the distinct `CDHair` objects in use you could change your request to:
(assuming the inverse relationship is named `persons`)

```
NSFetchRequest* req = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"CDHair"];
req.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"persons.@count != 0"];
```

This should give you all distinct `CDHair` objects being used by `CDPerson`s in your store.

Comment: Cool. In my testing I did find that I got back a distinct list of NSObjectIDs that reflected the distinct hair that I expect. I think this works because each CDHair has a unique ID, all the redheads share the same CDHair instance. I have to admit, I like your implementation of the fetch distinct request and will convert to use it since it returns living instances.

Comment: You are right about the distinct results, i've edited my answer to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to get color property like this?

```
NSArray* fetchResults = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
for (NSDictionary* hair in fetchResults) {
  NSLog(@"Hair Color is:", [hair objectForKey:@"color"]);
}
```