# NSManagedObjectID returns a string while requesting distinct NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to request distinct results using my NSFetchedResult. I tried to use the answer posted here: [What class is returned when requesting distinct NSManagedObject property instances from Core-Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840614/what-class-is-returned-when-requesting-distinct-nsmanagedobject-property-instanc) to use the `NSMangedObjectID` in order to get the actual NSManagedObject. Here is the `NSFetchedResult` code:

```
//Unique fetch request
    NSFetchRequest *uniqueFetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"EntityName"];
    [uniqueFetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"name"]];
    [uniqueFetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
    [uniqueFetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
    [uniqueFetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    [uniqueFetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    uniqueResults = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[context executeFetchRequest:uniqueFetchRequest error:&error]];
    NSManagedObjectID *mid = uniqueResults[0][@"name"];
    EntityData *card = (EntityData *)[context objectWithID:mid];
```

However, `[uniqueResults[0][@"name"]` is returning a NSString with the actual `name` of the NSManagedObject it found rather than something like `0x8b7b120 <x-coredata://C7E53293-94C7-444D-8162-167B1D66A961/Hair/p33>` (which is what was returned in the link I posted). Because it is now a NSString, `[context objectWithID:mid]` crashes and gives me the following error: `[__NSCFString persistentStore]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc47b170`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake here is trying to treat your `name` (`NSString` property) as a relationship.

Your request will return all distinct `name` attribute values (existing for the `EntityName` entity) in an array of dictionaries.

If 2 (or more) objects could have the same name, which object ID do you expect to get back?

If you want to segment your data based on a property value, I would suggest you use a `NSFetchedResultsController` and specify the `sectionNameKeyPath:` to match your needs.

**Edit:**
If your OK with **unstable** results you could try:

```
NSFetchRequest* r = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Ingredient"];
r.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
r.propertiesToGroupBy = @[@"name"];

NSExpressionDescription* objectIdDesc = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
objectIdDesc.name = @"objectID";
objectIdDesc.expression = [NSExpression expressionForEvaluatedObject];
objectIdDesc.expressionResultType = NSObjectIDAttributeType;

r.propertiesToFetch = @[objectIdDesc,@"name"];

NSArray* res = [context executeFetchRequest:r error:nil];
```

But I see no use for this kind of fetch

Comment: Basically, my Entity has two attributes: name and releaseDate. There could be multiple entities with the same name, but each of them will have a unique releaseDate. I'm trying to perform a fetch that will only return one entity for each name. Example: I have "Dodge Neon" - "12/2010" and "Dodge Neon" - "1/2011". I want my fetch to only return one of those two. (I already have it sorting the NSFetchRequest by the releaseDate attribute)

Comment: What makes it unstable? This kind of fetch is very useful for trading card games. The same card will occasionally be reprinted, so when making a deck builder for the game, it would be useful to be able to only show one copy of each reprinted card so that while searching for a card, the user isn't presented with 10 versions of the same card.

Comment: It is not always the same object that is returned as the representative of the group.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [collection operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html)

```
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"EntityName"];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    uniqueResults = [results valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.name"];
```